# Invoking a method AFTER a wcf service operation has returned its result

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service operation and I want a call to the operation to start a long running method, however I want the operation to return its result BEFORE the long running method finishes.

I have tried using an IParameterInspector implementation, but the result of the operation is not returned to the client until the long running method has completed.

How should I go about achieving this as anything I start from the operation seems to have to finish before the result is returned to the client?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it at the server, take a look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/05/17/wcf-extensibility-ioperationinvoker.aspx, it shows how to bypass the operation (it's a caching scenario, but it can be adapted to your problem).

If you want to do it at the client, you can simply call the operation asynchronously, it will return right away. And when the long-running operation completes, you'll get a notification (callback or event) that its results are ready.

Comment: This is an interesting and viable approach. I guess I view using WCF extensions primarily for infrastructure type responsibilities. This appears to me more of a business process concern so I'd probably would still go the queuing route. Thanks for the participation, it's always good to get different points of view!!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with a standard request/response type binding in WCF because as you found out, you won't get a response until the service has completed processing (or times out). 
To do what you want, you'll need a service where you can trigger the long running operation and then poll for completion status & response results.

The netMsmqBinding supports this scenario in WCF. All the operations for this binding must be a one-way call since you are only putting a message in a queue for processing. You'll need to have another endpoint or service configured with a request/response binding for the polling method. A good [overview of the netMsmqBinding is here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731089.aspx)